# Cannot download Epic Cloud saves on Heroic Games Launcher

Tags: linux, heroic-games-launcher

The save download progress seems stuck.

I tried Filament which supports save sync on Heroic. I scrolled down to 'Cloud Saves Sync' and expanded. Then I chose a directory as a save location. I selected the sync option as 'Download'.

Here is the log:

```
[Core] INFO: Trying to re-use existing login session...
[cli] INFO: Got 12 remote save game(s)
[cli] INFO: Checking "Filament" (14a38161ad3c45adab18425415b5df3d)
[cli] INFO: Overriding save path with "/home/meraj/.wine-10/drive_c/users/meraj/Local Settings/Application Data/Filament/Saved/SavedGames"...
[cli] INFO: Cloud save for "Filament" is newer:
[cli] INFO: - Cloud save date: 2023-03-15 10:16:01
[cli] INFO: - Local save date: N/A

[cli] INFO: Downloading remote savegame...

[Core] INFO: Deleting old save files...
[Core] INFO: Downloading "14a38161ad3c45adab18425415b5df3d/manifests/2023.03.15-10.16.01.manifest"...
[Core] CRITICAL: No chunks were available, aborting. Try running "legendary clean-saves 14a38161ad3c45adab18425415b5df3d" and try again.
```

Tried finding the location of "legendary" on my PC but no result.

```
$ whereis legendary
legendary:
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does `legendary clean-saves 14a38161ad3c45adab18425415b5df3d` do?

Comment: Sorry for not including that detail in the question. I tried to find the location of `legendary` on my PC, but didn't find it. Even `apt-cache search legendary` didn't give any relevant results.